# Handling Inequality with condition

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have verifying inequality using Mathematica using `Simplify` command

For Example

I want to check whether inequality `a<f` hold based on the following assumptions

```
a<b
b=d
d=e
e<f

b=d;d=e;Simplify[a<f,{a<b,e<f}]
```

Result is `True`

Now I have complex Scenario. In this case, I have assumptions

```
    If x>y then AF(l,x)>AF(l,y) 
    AF(l,r+1)>AF(l,r)
    AF(l+1,r+2)=AF(l,AF(l,r+1))
    AF(l+1,r+1)=AF(l,AF(l,r))
```

I want to prove `AF(l+1,r+2)>AF(l+1,r+1)`. Please suggest me the best way to write Mathematica code to handle the above Scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by `x>y->AF(l,x)>AF(l,y)`?

Comment: If x>y then AF(l,x)>AF(l,y)

Comment: Tom, then the syntax is not the one of Mathematica was used here. Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation type there `If` in the text field and Enter. After fixing the syntax try `Reduce` instead of `Simplify`.